# Prevent/disable delete confirmation in edit mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I'm trying to disable the pop-up that appears when you try to delete a face or a vertex. I'm not talking about a pop up for when you delete an object, just a face or something. Why is this even a feature? Selection modes only enable you to select certain things anyway, why on Earth do I need to confirm that yes, in vertex select, I want the vertices I selected to be deleted. Why can't I, I dunno, just delete the thing I selected?

Answer (score 3):

When deleting multiple faces, for example, one may or may not want to delete only the faces, not the edges between them. Or when deleting edges, one may or may not want to keep the vertices that would be deleted if they weren't connected to anything else. One may also want to delete the vertices of a selected face, for example, without the need to change what to select.

If you find that clicking on the buttons in this menu is slowing you down, you can use the keys:

- **X** then **1** - to delete vertices.
- **X** then **2** - to delete edges.
- **X** then **3** - to delete faces.

You can also assign a shortcut to those functions doing this:

- Open the menu with the button as if you would click on it.
- Right click the button.
- Click on *Assign Shortcut*.
- Insert your key combination or mouse button.

There is no way that i know for creating a shortcut or changing the current deleting one to one that will delete geometry based on the select mode that you currently are, maybe there is one already.

Comment: Good answer. It seems that Xcool233 never really needed anything of this, otherwise a question like "why would I want to delete anything else then what the selection mode suggests?" wouldn't come up. I for one very often use e.g. face select if I want to delete vertices because it's much quicker to select some faces (especially n-gons with many vertices) and delete all the comprising vertices instead of having to select all those vertices on their own. And things like "Only Faces" or "Only Edges & Faces" would be even harder to do just from the context of the selection mode.